# What is the correct way to import the blocks-editor?

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I was following a blocks tutorial that was using @wordpress/editor to import some components and everything was working correctly but I was getting tons of deprecation warnings in the browser all saying I should be using @wordpress/block-editor instead.

So I replaced it and installed the block editor in npm:

```
npm install @wordpress/block-editor --save
```

then in my plugins.php I added the dependency:

```
wp_register_script(
    'testblocks-editor-script',
    plugins_url('dist/editor.js', __FILE__),
    array('wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-element', 'wp-block-editor')
);
```

added to my webpack.config.js:

```
externals: {
        "@wordpress/blocks": ["wp", "blocks"],
        "@wordpress/i18n": ["wp", "i18n"],
        "@wordpress/element": ["wp", "element"],
        "@wordpress/block-editor": ["wp", "blockEditor"]
}
```

So now any time I save my previously working post in Wordpress I get this error in the browser's console and I am not able to edit:

***TypeError: _wordpress_block_editor__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ is undefined  parent.js:35***

I would think this is the relevant line in parent.js:

```
import { InnerBlocks, InspectorControls } from "@wordpress/block-editor";

...

edit: ({ className, attributes, setAttributes }) => {

    return (
        <div className={`${className}-test`}>      // this is line 35
```

Is my externals declaration incorrect?

Comment: I suggest you to use the `wp-scripts` package to build your scripts. [See details here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/javascript/js-build-setup/)